# Group by aggregate in pandas as where clause

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to run a row filtering and grouping on a pandas df dataframe without success. The SQL equivalent is (once df is imported into a SQL DB):

```
select column1, column2, count(*)
from table
group by column1, column2
having count(*)>1
order by column1, column2;
```

I have tried in the dataframe df with:

```
f[df.groupby(['column1', 'column2']).size()>1]
```

but I got a ValueError:

> ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'Python object' but got
> 'long long'.

I don't know if it is possible to perform this operation without resorting to other packages than the ones included in pandas.

Comment: Can you try to use it as :

`df.groupby(['column1', 'column2']).agg(count=('column1', 'size')).reset_index().query('count > 1').sort_values(['column1', 'column2'])`
And
Let me know, if it works ?

Answer (score 1):

We have `groupby` + `size` in pandas. Also groupby automatically sorts the values by the grouping columns

```
c = ['column1', 'column2']
df.groupby(c, as_index=False).size().query('size > 1')
```